# variables in haskell change without logic when I repeat them

Tags: haskell, math, encryption, functional-programming, rsa

Hello everybody this is my first question here. I just going crazy because of this and not found any information about it...

This is an example of the original code to simulate the problem:

```
module Code where
import Data.List

list e = [e, e*2 .. 10000]

exp1 z e = (((elemIndices 0 (map (`mod` e) (map (+1) (list z))))!!0 +1)*z +1) `div` e

prub v1 v2 e l = map (`mod` (v1*v2)) (map (product) (map (replicate (exp1 ((v1-1)*(v2-1)) e)) l))
```

this code with the following variables `(31 11 7 [235,302,210,123,255])` returns this list: `[106,70,246,160,277]`. But this isn't what I looking for.

But if I change the `(v1*v2)` for 341 which is the product of `v1*v2` (`11*31` in the example) the output is the following list `[20,15,12,30,19]`. This it's what I want.

```
prub v1 v2 e l = map (`mod` 341) (map (product) (map (replicate (exp1 ((v1-1)*(v2-1)) e)) l))
```

So why exist different returns with the EXACT SAME values?

Sorry for my english. If you want to know what I want to make is a RSA encryption in haskell

Edit: forgive me for the mistakes in code, I edit the text and put a reproducible code.

Comment: For me it is always returning the "wrong" [106,70,246,160,277] even if I replace `(v1*v2)` by 341. Also, there are a few error in the code that you have posted. Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: You've declared `exp` twice.

Comment: did you maybe type 34 or 31 instead of 341?

Comment: I solve the problems in the text. Now you can run this code to see for yourselves

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as Noughtmare; swapping in `341` for `v1*v2` in the definition of `prub` yields the same result: `[106,70,246,160,277]`. 
More broadly, it sounds like the first step to understanding what's going on at your end will be to lay out your different test cases next to each other in a more structured way, so you can be sure of what you're seeing and under what circumstances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is a difference in the inferred type for `prub` in the two versions.  The "wrong" version uses `Int`, which overflows, while the "right" version uses `Integer`, which doesn't overflow.

In your original version (that uses `v1*v2`), the function `exp1` has inferred type `Int -> Int -> Int`.  This is because the `elemIndices` call has return type `[Int]`, which results in the types of the arguments and return value being similarly inferred as `Int`.  Because you have:

```
exp1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

the call to `exp1` in `prub` with its first argument `((v1-1)*(v2-1))` causes both `v1` and `v2` to be assigned type `Int`.  When you take a `mod` by `v1*v2`, this causes the type of `l` to be inferred as `[Int]`.

In contrast, when you replace `v1*v2` with `341`, even though the types of `v1` and `v2` are still inferred as `Int`, the type of `341` is inferred as an unspecified `Integral`.  The resulting type for `prub` is:

```
prub :: Integral b => Int -> Int -> Int -> [b] -> [b]
```

When you call `prub` in your test case using `341` in place of `v1*v2`:

```
prub 31 11 7 [235,302,210,123,255]
```

the type of the final argument defaults to `[Integer]` avoiding the overflow.

To fix it, you should provide a means to perform the necessary calculations on `Integer` instead of `Int`.  I guess I'd recommend explicit type signatures and a `fromIntegral` call to convert between `Int` and `Integer` where necessary:

```
list :: Int -> [Int]
list e = [e, e*2 .. 10000]

exp1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
exp1 z e = (((elemIndices 0 (map (`mod` e) (map (+1) (list z))))!!0 +1)*z +1) `div` e

prub :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
prub v1 v2 e l = map (`mod` fromIntegral (v1*v2)) (map (product) (map (replicate (exp1 ((v1-1)*(v2-1)) e)) l))
```

Comment: Wow man, you just explained in a wonderfull way, thank you!! I'm new in haskell so I will continue lerning about types.

Comment: Wow. In retrospect it feels like it should have been obvious, but the first thing I did when I copied the code was add type annotations, and it's _hard_ to provide explicit types for the existing code that will yield the "correct" answer!